# include an object inside another

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
project = {id: 1}
milestone = { id: 1, name: "milestone a" }
tasks = [{ name: 'task a' }, { name: 'task b' }]
```

I need to create an object, from the three objects above, that looks like this:

```
project = { id:1, milestone: {id: 1, name: "milestone a", tasks: [...]} }
```

I tried project.milestone = milestone, ... but it gets impossible to work with if I have many variables and assignments.

So my question is, how can I include an object in another and modify the parent, so that:

```
a = {id: 1}
b = {id: 2}
a.magic_method(b) // => {id: 1, b: {id: 2}}
```

Comment: You mean like `Object.defineProperty(obj, 'name', {value: {some: 'value'}});`? PS: You'll have an easier time at it when you only have 1 variable (an object): `var myVars = {};` and replace al `var foo = ..` with `myVar.foo = ...`

Comment: @alex, is this all object dynamic?

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura Yes.

Comment: @Alex: No, we do not include tags in titles. We write tags in tags.

Comment: @Alex, is any relationship among these object?

Comment: @HiteshSiddhapura No.

Comment: The big question is: Why would you ever want to do that? Is there any use case that justifys this logic?

Comment: @Amberlamps DNA Sequencing.

Comment: @Alex: That does not answer my question. I have never heard a more broad answer than this :) I mean a use case where you MUST use your approach!

Comment: @Alex, I have added answer, please check

Comment: maybe a['b'] = {}; a['b']['c'] = {}; will suit your case ? also have a look at jquery or underscorejs .extend and .clone functions

Comment: Oh i just realized, you want to have `tasks` merged into `milestone`, too, i updated the Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

Oh i just realized, you want to have `tasks` merged into `milestone` and `milestone` merged into projects.

In this case you have to merge a merged object.

But it would be rather be easier to setup your object structure like this from the beginning, like @Amberlamps and @Elias Van Ootegem suggest.

I Updated the answer

Edit2:
  changed the typecheck to use `instanceof` because `{}.toString.call(o)` returns the objects ClassName, which can be anything for a nodeElement and "[object global]" for `window`

---

You could write a merge function, which merges properties from multiple Objects into one.

```
var merge = (function () {
    var initThis = this;
    return function () {
        var len = arguments.length - 1,
            srt, tmp;
        if ("function" === typeof arguments[arguments.length - 1]) srt = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
        else {
            srt = function (a, b, prop) {
                if (!prop) return a;
                return a[prop];
            };
            len++;
        }
        var merge = this === initThis ? {} : this;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) inner(arguments[i], merge);

        function inner(obj2, obj1) {
            if (obj2 instanceof Array) {
                if (!obj1) obj1 = [];
                if (typeof obj1 != "object") obj1 = (tmp = srt(obj1, obj2, null), tmp) === obj2 ? [] : tmp;
                for (var i = 0; i < obj2.length; i++) if (!obj1[i] && typeof obj2[i] == "object") obj1[i] = inner(obj2[i]);
                    else if (obj1[i] && typeof obj2[i] == "object") obj1[i] = inner(obj2[i], obj1[i]);
                else if (obj1[i]) obj1[i] = srt(obj1, obj2, i) || obj1[i];
                else obj1[i] = obj2[i];
            } else if (obj2 instanceof Object) {
                if (!obj1) obj1 = {};
                if (typeof obj1 != "object") obj1 = (tmp = srt(obj1, obj2, null), tmp) === obj2 ? {} : tmp; //If obj2 is returned, set to empty obj to allow deep cloning
                for (var prop in obj2) {
                    var isObj = "object" === typeof obj2[prop];
                    if (!obj1[prop] && isObj) obj1[prop] = inner(obj2[prop]);
                    else if (obj1[prop] && isObj) obj1[prop] = inner(obj2[prop], obj1[prop]);
                    else if (obj1[prop]) obj1[prop] = srt(obj1, obj2, prop) || obj1[prop];
                    else obj1[prop] = obj2[prop];
                }
            } else {
                throw new SyntaxError ("expected " + obj2 + " to be of type object");
            }
            return obj1;
        }
        return merge;
    };
})();
```

The merge function accepts *n* parameters, where the last one can be a disambiguation function, which gets called when 2 properties of the currently merging objects are the same.

This disambiguation function gets called with 3 parameters:

- `a`

  - The current first object which properties get merged.
- `b`

  - The current second object which properties get merged.
- `prop`

  - The name of the Property which gets merged

The return value of the function will be assigned to the current merging propertie.

e.g `return a[prop]` would always assign the value of the first object, if theres a conflict.

If no function is passed as last argument, the default behaviour is: keep the value of the first Object.

Now we have to call `merge` on `milestone` and `tasks`, and then `merge` `project` with the merged `milestone` Object, which looks like this.

```
project = {id: 1};
milestone = { id: 1, name: "milestone a" };
tasks = [{ name: 'task a' }, { name: 'task b' }];


var merged = merge (project,{milestone: merge (milestone , {tasks:tasks} )});
                                       //^^^ mergeception
                                                           //^^^ Wrap it because you want the complete 'tasks' object, not merge the properties this time.

console.log (JSON.stringify(merged));
/* {
"id": 1,
"milestone": { //<- milestone in merged/project
    "id": 1,
    "name": "milestone a",
    "tasks": [{          //<- tasks in milestone
        "name": "task a"
    }, {
        "name": "task b"
    }]
  }
} */
```

you can see it returns a merged object.

Heres a [**Demo on JSBin**](http://jsfiddle.net/Glutamat/nK3Ux/)

Or if you want it the jQuery way..

`var merged = $.extend(project, {milestone : $.extend (milestone, {tasks:tasks}) });`

Answer (score 2):

You could you `$.extend` :

```
$.extend(project, {milestone: milestone}, {tasks: tasks});
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/hDWef/

Comment: Thanks but in your example, tasks are not included in the milestone.

Comment: If I understood OP correctly, you can not always know that `milestone` is called "milestone". He is looking for a more generic approach.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$.extend(project, {milestone: $.extend(milestone,{tasks:tasks})});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of knowing what the human readable name of your variable is. So you will find no magical function that fullfills your requirements.

Furthermore, you will never need such a function, because YOU decide what your variables are called like. So instead of looking for a magical function, just write your variable name as an object property:

```
var a = { id: "idA" };
var b = { id: "idB" };

a.b = b;
// it does not get more simple than that!
```

Comment: @r043v: You did not understand the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you're after. I created it as a function so that you can reuse it.

The idea:

`function (parent, {object list of children to combine to parent});`

The source:

```
var project = {id: 1};
var milestone = { id: 1, name: "milestone a" };
var tasks = [{ name: 'task a' }, { name: 'task b' }];
var finalList;

function combine(parent, combineList) {
    var len = combineList.length;
    var returnList = {}

    // Add values from the parent, in our case 'project'
    for (prop in parent) {
        returnList[prop] = parent[prop];
    }

    // Add in children
    for (obj in combineList) {
        returnList[obj] = combineList[obj];
    }

    return returnList;
}

finalList = combine(
    project, {
        'milestone': milestone, 
        'tasks': tasks
    });

console.log(finalList);
// finalList = {"id":1,"milestone":{"id":1,"name":"milestone a"},"tasks":[{"name":"task a"},{"name":"task b"}]}
```